# Is a given date older than a week?

Tags: java

The program that I am developing needs to determine if a given date is older than a week. I have come up with the following code:

`((new Date()).getTime() - date.getTime()   > 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000)`

Tell me if the code is correct. Help me write correct code if it's incorrect. Also, if you have better ways to code, let me know.

Comment: Why don't you simply fill your program with test cases?

Comment: It would have been quicker to just try it than write this question!

Comment: `(new Date()).getTime()` is an expensive way of writing `System.currentTimeMillis()`

Comment: Sometimes I think that people believe their computer will yell at them if their code is wrong, so they are afraid to run it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coming from the same country, I think I understand why she posted this question. The reason is quite complicated and and you may not understand unless you have a working understanding of the culture. Anyway, saying the following code is a better way would suffice.

`System.currentTimeMillis() - date.getTime()   > 7 * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000`

Comment: Then try to enlighten us here! And why would it suffice when OP asked in a general way and was given a reason why the code is **not** correct generally?

Comment: In my country, most developers would code this problem by calling getters and do some complicated algorithms. Her algorithms might be considered expert and maybe she is asking you guys here on stack overflow to agree with her. That way when she argues with her colleagues, she is in a better position.

Comment: Thanks everyone who tried to contribute. Here, I am having to work with programmers who are not very advanced. As user3350447 pointed out, I was confused by the comments of my colleagues. Today I learned a lesson. I am not supposed to ask questions like this on this site.

PS: I am not a she. A he. My name is spelled ဆႏၵေအာင္, not စႏၵာေအာင္ :)

Comment: Without knowing your script I already guessed that from the picture... ;-)

Answer (score 0):

As stated in the comments, you should have run the code and have a test for it.

Concerning correctness, it is not correct for all cases, since for example it does not respect summer/winter time. So if you have an hour shift in the middle of your time range you get a different result as without. Additionally, Date has no timezone information, so in many cases you experience trouble when comparing dates created by different machines.

That is one of the reasons that you should almost always use APIs for date/time calculations. Since Java 8 is not public yet, you probably have to live with the ugly existing classes or use one of the available open source APIs in this regard - but, don't do it by yourself.